# Image not mapping correctly on a square

Tags: opengl, graphics

I am attaching my code for mapping a image on a square but image is not mapping correctly[image: Image to be mapped]

the final image is getting tiled.

Please let me know how to correct this.

```
GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename )
{

  GLuint texture;
  int width, height;
  unsigned char * data;
  FILE * file;
  file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
  if ( file == NULL )
    {
      printf("\nThe file is not found"); 
       return 0;
     }
   width = 512;
   height = 512;
   data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
   //int size = fseek(file,);
   fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
   fclose( file );
   glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
   glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
   glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL );
   glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
   glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
   glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP );
   glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP );
   gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,   data );
free( data );
return texture;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
void display(void)
{

// CLEAR THE WINDOW
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
light();
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity(); 
glTranslatef(0,0,-5);
glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height/2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
drawObject();
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  void drawSquare()

{
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
  //  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
   glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);  
   glVertex2f(-0.2f, 0.2f);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);// x, y
   glVertex2f( 0.2f, 0.2f);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
   glVertex2f( 0.2f,  -0.2f);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
   glVertex2f(-0.2f,  -0.2f);
glEnd();



}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    void drawObject(void)

    {   
      // push the current matrix
      glPushMatrix();
      // apply the translation
      glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     GLuint  texture;
     texture =  LoadTexture(FName );
     glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

     drawSquare();
```

}

[image: Output from the software]

Comment: Is the width and height really 512px? That might explain it

Comment: @MadcoreTom Could you explain why?

Comment: I have checked the BMP image  is 512 X 512 pixels in size.

Comment: It looks like multiple columns of pixels could be interleved. If you're just reading bytes from a standard BMP file then I'd expect you would run into problems. Just looking at the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format I can see some padding on each row, plus a header that it seems like you're not handling

Comment: Thanks for the help @MadcoreTom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem got solved as the BMp image was saved in 32 bit Depth.
 after saving the image in 24 bit depth  the opengl mapped it correctly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you got one additional problem and that is the use of `GL_CLAMP` and using texture coordinate `0.0` and `1.0` which are out of texture. It will create 1 texel distortion on the edges of your square. If you need perfect mapping then there are two possible solutions:

1. **shift texture coordinates by half of pixel**

   if your texture has size `sz` in pixels then just change the coordinates to:

   ```cpp
   0.0 + (0.5/sz)
   1.0 - (0.5/sz)
   ```
2. **use wrap extension `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`**

   so just change `GL_CLAMP` to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` and use `0.0,1.0` as you do now. In case you do not have `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` defined add:

   ```cpp
   #ifndef GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
   #define GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE 0x812F
   #endif
   ```

   Beware your gfx driver have to support this extension (however I do not know any gfx card that does not have this)